# Kafka - Multiple Consumers

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have a simple Java application where produces some messages and consumes, 1 topic and 6 partitions. I want to have multiple consumers so that each message can be splitted into different consumers. I have one consumer and want to have 2, however I am a bit confused while trying to do. It is working with CLI but how can I create multiple consumers in a same consumer group in Java code?

Comment: What exactly is confusing?  If you want more than one consumer, then run your Java application JAR twice.

Comment: I thought I need to use Multithreading approach, just to create multiple consumers in my Java application.

Comment: You could, but that's not necessary.